How to wrap a series of numbers into a table of selected cells? in LibreOffice Calc
In LibreOffice Calc, how to wrap a series of numbers into a table of selected cells so that they stop at the end of the highlighted row, the right side of the table where it ends and have it continue off at the left of the next column below it?
Here is what it is doing - I’m very close to succeeding - but the numbers continue on endlessly in the first row. See screenshot:

I need them to stop at the end of the blue selection and continue again in the next blue column below.
Here is the ODT file.
And here is an example of a series of numbers:
10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32
-Thanks!

I have come to believe that using scripting in LibreOffice and it's siblings is overly complex.
Python-based such scripts begins with import uno but then embarks on overly wordy references to complex objects(!?).
Below is a simple python-based solution to your problem;
you may use this as basis for a pure *.py script.


I put your list of numbers in a file
$ cat numsplit.txt
10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32

Then wrote a 'one-liner' to read 250000 characters from stdin,
which I then split up in a more readable format,
and placed that in a file, ...
$ cat numsplit.sh
python -c "\
import sys;\
nums=sys.stdin.read(250000).replace(' ','').split(',');\
lines=[nums[i:i+10] for i in range(0,len(nums),10) ];\
print('\n'.join([','.join(lst) for lst in lines]))"

... to be executed like this:
$ source numsplit.sh  <numsplit.txt
10,31,34,6,14,3,16,23,6,33
15,32,10,31,34,6,14,3,16,23
6,33,15,32,10,31,34,6,14,3
16,23,6,33,15,32,10,31,34,6
14,3,16,23,6,33,15,32,10,31
34,6,14,3,16,23,6,33,15,32
10,31,34,6,14,3,16,23,6,33
15,32,10,31,34,6,14,3,16,23
6,33,15,32,10,31,34,6,14,3
16,23,6,33,15,32,10,31,34,6
14,3,16,23,6,33,15,32,10,31
34,6,14,3,16,23,6,33,15,32
10,31,34,6,14,3,16,23,6,33
15,32

$

There are two 10 in the python-code,
change them to any reasonable number and your lines will have that number of items.
replace(...) in the midst of it removes any space-characters,
and the subsequent split(',') splits (separates) the items.
This is then split once more into lines, with a list of items per line, each line as a separate list.
the list comprehension in the print() then creates the output from the  list of lists.
Import the output into any spreadsheet and it will create your data-table accordingly.
More help, i.e. use the clipboard for all IO to the script:
man xclip  
man xclipboard


All this can of course be the basis for a LibrOffice-Calc script!
All you need to figure out is HOW to grab the numbers from the firs line of cells, run the above, and at the end, instead of printing, place the items back into Calc.

Thank  you very much!

Hmm... please read https://superuser.com/tour - for understanding superuser

Am I not allowed to say thank you?

you are! But note the text about votes in the tour ;-)

Welcome to Super User @Username2324! Some people regard saying thank you as "fluff" which adds no value to the answer or your question. The point about voting is that if the answer was useful to you - you have not said it is -  please vote on the answer using the voting buttons. If you mouse over the voting buttons they have text which describes when to use them. This adds points or "Reputation" to Hannu's score. Questions have similar voting buttons which I will use in a moment! Have a nice day.

Here is python-uno code to insert the values into a Calc sheet, borrowing some code from the other answer.
import uno

MAXCOL = 'O'  # from the screenshot in the question
nums = (
    10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16,
    23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31,
    34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6,
    33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6,
    14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15,
    32, 10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3,
    16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32,10, 31, 34, 6, 14, 3, 16, 23, 6, 33, 15, 32)
MAXCOLNUM = ord(MAXCOL) - ord('A') + 1
lines = [nums[i:i+MAXCOLNUM]
    for i in range(0, len(nums), MAXCOLNUM)]
oSheet = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument().getSheets().getByIndex(0)
for row, line in enumerate(lines):
    for col in range(len(line)):
        oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(col, row)
        oCell.setValue(line[col])

I'm not sure why @Hannu thinks python-uno is overly complex. To me, the code looks easy enough to understand, and there's no need to create intermediate files this way. Compared to MS Office VBA, the UNO API is generally considered lower level, so it can be more difficult for simple tasks but better for advanced tasks.
This could be done with spreadsheet formulas instead of a script. To do this, use MOD with spreadsheet functions such as INDIRECT to grab the appropriate value for each cell. Whether that's easier or not depends on the specifics of what you need.
